# Model run time in auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to run an `auto.arima` model for daily sales. I have many predictor variables in the model. When I run `auto.arima`, AIC significantly reduces in value with the predictor values. Ex:
`auto.arima (sales,xreg=xreg)`

But when I try to actually get the forecast, the model doesn't run. 
ex: `salesforecast=auto.arima(sales,xreg=xreg)`
R times out or doesn't produce any results. Is there a way to enter all the predictor variables in the model without causing it to not timeout?

Code is below.

```
salests=ts(sales,frequency=365.25,start=c(2010,1))
xreg=cbind(Vars=model.matrix(~as.factor(data$Sunday)),Friday=data$Friday,Pub20=data$Public.20.10,Sale1=data$Sale.Last.for.1,Sale2=data$Sale.Last.for.2,Sale3=data$Sale.Last.for.3,Sale4=data$Sale.Last.for.4,Sale5=data$Sale.Last.for.5,Sale6=data$Sale.Last.for.6,Sale7=data$Sale.Last.for.7,Sale8=data$Sale.Last.for.8,Sale9=data$Sale.Last.for.9,Sale10=data$Sale.Last.for.10,OneBef=data$X1.Day.before.Sale,TwoBef=data$X2.Day.before.Sale,ThreeBef=data$X3.Day.before.Sale,FourBef=data$X4.Day.before.Sale,FiveBef=data$X5.Day.before.Sale,Monday=data$Monday,Tuesday=data$Tuesday,Wednesday=data$Wednesday,Thursday=data$Thursday,Jan=data$Jan,Feb=data$Feb,Mar=data$Mar,Apr=data$Apr,May=data$May,Jun=data$Jun,Jul=data$Jul,Aug=data$Aug,Sep=data$Sep,Oct=data$Oct,Nov=data$Nov)

xreg=xreg[,-1]

colnames(xreg)=c("Sunday","Friday","Pub20","Sale1","Sale2","Sale3","Sale4","Sale5","Sale6","Sale7","Sale8","Sale9","Sale10","OneBef","TwoBef","ThreeBef","FourBef","FiveBef","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov")

salesforecast=auto.arima(sales,xreg=xreg)
```

Comment: `auto.arima` fits the model, `forecast(model, xreg = reg)` returns the forecast for that model.

Comment: So the problem might be my lack of experience with R. I thought the dummy variables are added in the xreg arguement

Comment: so when I did that I received an error. Code:
salesfit=auto.arima(sales)
salesforecast=forecast(salesfit,xreg=xreg)
Error in if (ncol(xreg) != ncol(object$call$xreg)) stop("Number of regressors does not match fitted model") : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: In this case you fit a model with regressors and tried to forecast without supplying the regressors. You must fit/forecast either with or without regressors.

Comment: Right I understand this, but when I try to fit with the regressors, I don't receive an error but the model will take forever to run. I can wait a whole day and it still wont be done running

Comment: Ok, can you upload your data-set somewhere and post a link? Also, check for missing/wrong values.

Comment: Sure thing. Where is the easiest place to load the data? I am new to this site.

Comment: @user3120266 Did you ever figure this out, running into the same issue